# React okta auth unable to login

Tags: reactjs

[image]    import { useOktaAuth } from "@okta/okta-react";

```
const Home = () => {
  const { oktaAuth, authState } = useOktaAuth();

  const login = async () => oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect();
  const logout = async () => oktaAuth.signOut("/");

  if (!authState) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (!authState.isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Not Logged in yet</p>
        <button onClick={login}>Login</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Logged in!</p>
      <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I am using react okta auth for login but getting some error while calling login.
Screenshot attached please take a look what can be the reason.

Comment: no screenshot attached

Comment: Sorry. Please check now. Attached

Comment: it seems your issue is not with Okta, based on CORS error in the log

Comment: How to fix this ?

Comment: your `clouddefense` is blocking your calls, so fix that. No idea, how to manage it